# How can I add any points in Manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

```
(* 5.3  1 *)
X = {x, 1 - x}
Y = {y, 1 - y}
A = {{2, -1}, {0, 1}}
B = {{-3, 3}, {1, -2}}
f1[x_, y_] = X.A.Y
f2[x_, y_] = X.B.Y
(* Print["Pago del Row Player en Eq-> ",f1[3/5,1/2]]
Print["Pago del Col Player en Eq-> ",f2[3/5,1/2]] *)
Manipulate[

 ParametricPlot[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",

  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize -> .036, Point[{f1[p, q], f2[p, q]}]}],

 Style["Representación de los pagos de Prisionero 1(abscisas) y \
Prisionero 2 (ordenadas) en el Dilema del Prisionero", 11, Bold],
 Delimiter,

 Style["Prisionero 1 juega la estrategia mixta(p,1-p), con el valor \
de p indicado a continuación", 10, Darker@Blue],
 {{p, 0}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Open"},
 Delimiter,

 Style["Prisionero 2 juega la estrategia mixta(q,1-q), con el valor \
de q indicado a continuación", 10, Darker@Orange],
 {{q, 0}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Open"},
 Delimiter,

 Style["Valores MAXIMIN", 11, Bold, Darker@Black],
 (*Style["Valor Maximin para Norm: 5/6",10,Darker@Gray],
 Style["Valor Maximin para Cliff: 5/6",10,Darker@Gray],*)

 Delimiter,
 Style["Estrategias de Equilibrio", 11, Bold, Darker@Black],
 Delimiter,
 Style["Nota.- Los años de carcel son los valores absolutos de lo \
indicado en los ejes. Se indican en negativo porque es algo \
malo/negativo", 10, Darker@Black],
 Style["Creado por Rafael Sanmartín", 10, 
  Darker@Black],

 ControlPlacement -> Left, SaveDefinitions -> True

 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I tried to add any point after `Epilog`, but I can't.

I want to add, for example, the points $(2,-3)$, $(-1,3)$, and $(0,1)$ or $(f_1(0.5), f_2(0.5))$ and $(f_1(0.4), f_2(0.3))$.

Comment: `(f1[0.5],...` yet you have `f1[x_, y_] ...`? Points such as `Point[{2, -3}]` are easily added to the Epilog expression...

Comment: \cormullion  I can´t add points. I don´t know how to do that.  I trid but no success

Comment: use `Point[{{f1[p, q], f2[p, q]},{2, -3}, {-1, 3} , {0, 1}}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.036], 
Point[{f1[p, q], f2[p, q]}], Blue, 
Point[{{2, -3}, {-1, 3} , {0, 1}}]}
```

I admit I was surprised that Mathematica refused to accept:

```
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.036], {
Point[{f1[p, q], f2[p, q],{2, -3}, {-1, 3} , {0, 1}}]}
```

Comment: f1[p, q] and f2[p, q] are scalars. So, of course you can't use `Point[{f1[p, q], f2[p, q],{2, -3}, {-1, 3} , {0, 1}}]`, you must use `Point[{{f1[p, q], f2[p, q]},{2, -3}, {-1, 3} , {0, 1}}]`.